# show where left of a html page

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to html and javacript and i know only the basics of them. So I want to create a html based web page.

```
<html>
<body>

uette like a man’s face, a marshy spot beside the river where the waterfowl were easily startled, a tall tree that looked like a man with his arms upraised. 
</body></html>
```

I am wondering whether there is a code to continue where I left from that page when I close and reopens it.
I tried searching on google for code but I couldn't find anything. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Take a looka at [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) or [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: You could save an item in the localStorage (look for localStorage API on mozilla developers network). This item could be the window.scrollTop for example. Then the next time the user opens the page, you retrieve this item and use it to set the scrollTop.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery and [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log('scroll')
    let doc = document.documentElement;
    let top = (window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop) - (doc.clientTop || 0);
    console.log('body top', top);
    localStorage.setItem('scroll', top);
  });

  var top = localStorage.getItem('scroll');
  console.log('top', top);
  $('body').scrollTop(top);
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 5300px; /* for scroll */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  uette like a man’s face, a marshy spot beside the r iver where the waterfowl were easily startled, a ta ll tree that looked like a man with his arms uprais ed. ............................. ..........................
</div>https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56059324/edit#
```

Comment: Thanks for your edit, but this answer cannot run with `stackoverflow snippet`, because the `localStorage` is not saved in this site for test